# Unable to use all configuration parameters with a custom configuration in gradle with kotlin-dsl

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

With gradle-groovy it is possible to have a custom configuration with a lot of parameters (group, name, version, ext, classifier):

```
configurations {
    explode
}

dependencies {
    explode (group: 'org.apache.samza', name: 'samza-shell', ext: 'tgz', classifier: 'dist', version: "$SAMZA_VERSION")
}
```

But I don't know how to do that with the kotlin-dsl. I tried:

```
val explode by configurations.creating

dependencies {
    explode(group = "org.apache.samza", name = "samza-shell",  ext = "tgz", classifier = "dist", version = samzaVersion)
    // "explode"(group = "org.apache.samza", name = "samza-shell",  ext = "tgz", classifier = "dist", version = samzaVersion)
}
```

but without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work this way:

```
val explode by configurations.creating

dependencies {
    explode(mapOf(
      "group" to "org.apache.samza",
      "name" to "samza-shell",
      "ext" to "tgz",
      "classifier" to "dist",
      "version" to "0.13.1"
      )
    )
}
```

To be honest, for the sake of brevity, I'd rather go with string interpolation.

Also, with groovy, a instance of `Map` is passed as well.

Comment: Yes, I go with `explode("org.apache.samza:samza-shell:$samzaVersion:dist@tgz")`